# javascript element.scrollBy does not scroll given distance

Tags: javascript, scroll

When I use element.scrollBy(x,y) in chrome (87) the elements viewport scroll-position (element.scrollTop) does not actually scroll the same value as expected and was given as arguments to scrollBy().

The difference is always in the range between 0.1 to 0.5 px and is different for different argument values.

I tested this for values between 1-30 for a display ratio of 1.75:

```
 1) actual:0.57, diff:0.43
 2) actual:1.71, diff:0.29
 3) actual:2.86, diff:0.14
 4) actual:4.00, diff:-0.00
 5) actual:4.57, diff:0.43
 6) actual:5.71, diff:0.29
 7) actual:6.86, diff:0.14
 8) actual:8.00, diff:0.00
 9) actual:8.57, diff:0.43
 10) actual:9.71, diff:0.29
 11) actual:10.86, diff:0.14
 12) actual:12.00, diff:-0.00
 13) actual:12.57, diff:0.43
 14) actual:13.71, diff:0.29
 15) actual:14.86, diff:0.14
 16) actual:16.00, diff:0.00
 17) actual:16.57, diff:0.43
 18) actual:17.71, diff:0.29
 19) actual:18.86, diff:0.14
 20) actual:20.00, diff:0.00
 21) actual:20.57, diff:0.43
 22) actual:21.71, diff:0.29
 23) actual:22.86, diff:0.14
 24) actual:24.00, diff:0.00
 25) actual:24.57, diff:0.43
 26) actual:25.71, diff:0.29
 27) actual:26.86, diff:0.14
 28) actual:28.00, diff:0.00
 29) actual:28.57, diff:0.43
```

There are 4 values that repeat in this order 0.00,0.43,0.29,0.14,...

I can make no sense out of or what the reason is for that. The only thing I found is that element.scrollTop and these functions can return fractions and not only integers, which has some relation to highDPI displays.

It is an issue for me, since I implement a mouse-drag scrolling function, which converts mousem-move events to scroll movements, and the movements are normally small in value, which means the error is rather big in relation, and the viewport scrolls not 1:1 to the mouse speed.

Firefox does not have the issue.

what am I missing here?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/90r7zetd/5/